# strange string format + pathname from fileupload in mysql

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, html

Hey guys I have a problem im uploading images to my project path the images are contained within ~/userdata/UserID/uploadedimage/image.jpg

I used the below method to upload and to store the path of the picture in my database.

```
    protected void UploadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (FileUploadControl.HasFile)
        {
            try
            {
                string theUserId = Session["UserID"].ToString();
                OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver}; Server=localhost; Database=gymwebsite2; User=root; Password=commando;");
                cn.Open();
                //string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/" + theUserId + "/uploadedimage/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
                FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

                OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('" + theUserId + "' , '" + fileuploadpath + "')", cn);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

            }

        }
    }
}
```

What I found is the path isnt the path of my project directory its something strange:

[image]

Here is a snippet from my database the first one idPictures = 1 is the correct path name I need.

idPictures = 2 is the one that the fileupload is inserting into my database?

How can I get it so it will give a path name like this:

```
~/userdata/2/uploadedimage/batman-for-facebook.jpg
```

**Edit:**

If I try this:

```
string fileuploadpath = ("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

            OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('"+theUserId+"','"+fileuploadpath+"')", cn);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

        }

    }
}

    }
```

I get the error:

**The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: The SaveAs method is configured to require a rooted path, and the path '~/userdata/1/uploadedimage/holypally.jpg' is not rooted.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it's treating backslashes as escape characters in your SQL statement. Don't forget, you're using `Server.MpaPath` - i.e. you're trying to find the Windows absolute filename for the file.

This is exactly the kind of thing that happens when you don't use parameterized SQL statements, but instead include what is essentially user-specified text into your SQL directly. **Don't do that.** Use a parameterized SQL command, specify the values separately and then you at least won't need to worry about wonky values.

Of course, you'll still need to work out whether you *really* wanted to store the translated path or not, but that's a different matter.

Comment: erm maybe so on the backlashes as idpictures 2 is missing them, but why isnt it saving like the first picturepath rather its giving a full path

Comment: @Garrith: You're calling `Server.MapPath` and inserting the result as the value for `picturepath`. Are you sure you understand what `Server.MapPath` does?

Comment: no I dont want the translated path and yes I understand on the parameterized SQL statements but id like to see first if I can get the pathname correct then worry about backlashes

Comment: well initially from what I heard MapPath was ~ hence why I used it I didnt know it translated the "full" path

Comment: does that mean I can remove it and set my own pathname?

Comment: @Garrith: If you don't want to use `MapPath`, just don't call it... just use Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName)

Comment: @Garrith: You need to distinguish between the value you're putting in the database and how you're saving the file. Maybe you need Server.MapPath in order to save the file, but not to put it in the database, for example... you need to get these things clear in your head so you can perform your own troubleshooting.

Comment: ok your right I do need it for the upload, should I create two strings in this case? One string for the actual upload and one string just to get the rooted pathname to store in the database?

Answer (score 0):

In order to answer my own question I had to create two strings one purely for fileupload and the other purely for database pathname storage:

```
        string filenameDB = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        string fileuploadpath = Server.MapPath("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
        FileUploadControl.SaveAs(fileuploadpath);
        string fileuploadpaths = ("~/userdata/"+theUserId+"/uploadedimage/")+filenameDB;
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";

        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Pictures (UserID, picturepath) VALUES ('"+theUserId+"','"+fileuploadpaths+"')", cn);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: The file could not be uploaded. The following error occured: " + ex.Message;

    }

}
```

}

```
    }
```